# Cuenta atrás que continúe al cambiar de activity

Tags: android-asynctask

Buenas me gustaría hacer un cronómetro que se inicie en un activity A y aunque el usuario pase a una activity B o C siga decrementando en segundo plano. 
Creo que la mejor opción es un asynctask pero no estoy seguro, tampoco sé cómo podría por ejemplo al pasar de la actividad B a la A, recuperar la información del asynctask que deje corriendo en A y actualizar el textview que muestra cuanto tiempo queda.

Creo que para recuperar la información del asynctask habrá que jugar con el método ón resume de la actividad A pero por más que Googleo no encuentro nada

Muchas gracias y perdón si no es una pregunta adecuada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se muy bien como tendras hecho o quieres que funcione este cronometro, pero creo que esto te podria servir.

Lo que necesitas es como pasar parametros entre actividades. En ese parametro le pasas el tiempo que ha pasado en el cronometro e instancias un cronometro en esa clase con el tiempo que ha pasado.

Nose si me has entindido muy bien o no pero te dejo un enlace de como se pasan parametros entre actividades.

https://geekytheory.com/tutorial-android-10-paso-de-parametros-entre-activities

Comment: Si si te entiendo,  voy pasando un bundle con el tiempo que queda en el temporizador al ir cambiando de activitys y en cada nueva activity inicio un temporizador con el parámetro tiempo del bundle, no es mal apaño sin duda, pero no sé la app que tengo en el móvil ( que venía por defecto) si tu pasas a otra app actividad o lo que sea sigue corriendo pero quizás sea la única manera como dices

Comment: No creo que como yo digo sea la unica manera, pero al igual que tu desconozco como se podria hacer de otra forma. Es la solucion mas correcta que se me a ocurrido al problema con lo poco que se sobre Android Studio. Espero que te sirva :P

Comment: de momento implementaré esa pero a ver si alguien tiene otra posibilidad,  me parece muy buena,  engorrosa pero al final las cosas tienen.qje funcionar, el como al usuario le da igual XD, muchas gracias